# Basic runtime script error on python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to point out that I am a beginner and that I started barely 48 hours ago.

I want to code a script that runs a page, enters username and password, click in the login button and clicks in a tab once logged in.

But I encounter an error, it only opens the page for me and does not enter any id/pw and click.

I tried to search and try some changes in the path but it doesn't change anything, and at worst doesn't launch my page anymore, I'm a little lost so I ask for your help please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpu7z.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the Selenium docs [Finding Web Elements](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/) 
So in your code,
import By `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` 
and use `wb.find_element(By.XPATH,"your_xpath")`

Comment: Okay thanks, I tested and now I have an error in this line: https://prnt.sc/DHzPFurcNwR1

Comment: @Asap "unterminated string literal" means you have the open quote `"` but no close quotation mark `"` at the end of the URL

Comment: Now https://prnt.sc/eLUFhbzgdgsl

Comment: @Asap you need to import webdriver  `from selenium import webdriver`